# Is there a VGA to Thunderbolt adapter that supports Lion?

Tags: vga, mini-displayport, thunderbolt

I have an old Toshiba desktop TV that I want to use as a second monitor for a very new MacMini.  All that the display has is VGA input. I already have an Apple display in my HDMI port, so I can't use a VGA to HDMI adapter.  Is there such a thing as a VGA to Thunderbolt adapter that supports Lion (Mac OS X 10.7)?

Answer (score 3):

[Monoprice](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=104&cp_id=10428&cs_id=1042802&p_id=5107&seq=1&format=2) has what you want.

[Apple](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB572Z/A?fnode=MTY1NDA5OQ&mco=MTA4MzU1NDg) as well.

This is a hardware thing, it has nothing to do with whether or not Lion supports it.

Comment: I was just about to say "And Lion is irrelevant" but you edited it in already...:)

Comment: I aim to please :)

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search confirms that there is an adapter from VGA to a mini display port. That means you can use a vga display in your thunderbolt port.  Thunderbolt is backward compatible so the VGA to mini display adapter should work for Thunderbolt

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of Thunderbolt/DisplayPort to VGA/DVI, but not the other way around. So you can use Apple products on non Apple displays, but you can't use non Apple laptops/notebooks on the latest Apple displays.

There's another thread here, but the solution they provide sounds quite expensive:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/37869/is-there-a-vga-to-thunderbolt-mini-displayport-adapter